# How passing an object instead of a type when pushing a view in a NavigationIOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm a new user of React Native and I'm trying to port some Swift code to Javascript using React Native.

In Swift, I've a class which is in charge of instantiate several objects and a viewController and to interconnect all the objects and set their references to the viewController.

Here is a basic version:

```
class A
{
  func instantiateView()
  {
    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0] as! UIWindow;
    let viewController = // Instantiate a view controller...viewController
    let a = // Instantiate an object.
    let b = // Instantiate an object.
    let c = // Instantiate an object.


    viewController.a = a;
    viewController.b = b;
    viewController.c = c;

    if let navController = window.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
    {
      navController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
  }
}
```

So as you can see above, I instantiated a view and set attributes to it.
But as far as I know with React Native, when I want to push a new view in a window, I have to pass the type of the view rather than an object.

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'My App',
          component: MyFirstView,
        }}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Here, I pass the type `MyFirstView` instead of an object of the `MyFirstView`. The problem is I can't set the attributes of this class before display it on the window.

I would rather instantiate the view this way:

```
class ReactNativeCrossPlatformModuleArchitectureApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var a = // First attribute
    var b = // Second attribute
    var c = // Third attribute

    var searchPageView = // Instantiate the View

    searchPageView.a = a;
    searchPageView.b = b;
    searchPageView.c = c;

    return (
      <React.NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'My App',
          component: searchPageView,
        }}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Does anybody know if there is such a way to instantiate a view using ReactNative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code for NavigatorIOS, you can see that when the component is passed in via a route, it is rendered as a child of a `RCTNavigatorItem` component.

```
<Component
    navigator={this.navigator}
    route={route}
    {...route.passProps}
/>
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Navigation/NavigatorIOS.ios.js#L613

Therefore it doesn't seem like there is a built-in way to do what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm looking for an idea of workaround.